# instagram-private-api 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, instagram, instagram-api

With difficulties on using the official Instagram API, I have been using `instagram-private-api` in my project to create post via Discord for around half a year. However, recently I have encounter 400 Bad Request issues while I didn't make any changes on it.
Below are the code for testing the post function upon executing in nodejs. Unfortunately I am still having the same error.

```js
const { IgApiClient } = require('instagram-private-api');
const { readFile } = require('fs').promises;

const ig = new IgApiClient();
const { IG_Username, IG_Password } = require('./Settings/config.json');

ig.state.generateDevice(IG_Username);

(async () => {
    try {
        await ig.simulate.preLoginFlow();
        await ig.account.login(IG_Username, IG_Password);
        const photo = await readFile(__dirname + '/Media/Post_Image_Publish.jpg');
        const post = await ig.publish.photo({
            file: photo,
            caption: `TESTING POSTING FROM NODE.JS`
        });
        console.log('Photo uploaded successfully');
        console.log(`Post URL: https://www.instagram.com/p/${post.media.code}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading photo to Instagram:', error);
    }
})();
```

Error: `IgResponseError: POST /rupload_igphoto/1680015944333_0_8212191953 - 400 Bad Request;`

What I can be sure is that:

- The login credentials are correct
- The Photo path is correct

Anyone have clues on it? It will be appreciated!

Comment: Check https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api/issues/1688

Comment: @James Although it is 400 Bad Request too, I am not sure if there case is having same reason as me since we are interacting different part with the api

Comment: what is your image dimension?

Comment: @rasulfahad 1075*1065 jpg